# How to get latitude longitude value from an address in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a form which has a textfield called `address`. I want to get the latitude and longitude value when the user types in his address in the textbox and clicks a button. How can I do this? I have done this using PHP but I need to get the latitude and longitude using Javascript/Google API. Any link to some tutorial?

Comment: i assume in php you used curl, in javascript you can use an ajax request.

Comment: Can you post a question and answer with how you did the form field and got the geocode for the address in php and it added on to the record in your db please!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a [Geocoding Request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingRequests) with AJAX.

Here is some [more information about Geocoding requests from Google.](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat)

And here is [information on AJAX from the JQuery site.](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/)